# Datatable - Orden numérico personalizado

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" border=1>
<thead>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Cost</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><th>Cust1</th><th>1,00</th><th>200,00</th></tr>
<tr><th>Cust2</th><th>0,00</th><th>0,00</th></tr>
<tr><th>Cust3</th><th>915,00</th><th>1.703,00</th></tr>
<tr><th>Cust4</th><th>1725.237,00</th><th>35.787,00</th></tr>
<tr><th>Cust5</th><th>405,00</th><th>90,00</th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Necesito ordenarlo de forma numérica.

El resultado final que espero es.
Al ordenar de forma ascendente la columna de "Cost" quede con el siguiente orden:
0,00 > 90,00 > 200,00 > 1.703,00 > 35.787,00.

He intentado con todos y cada uno de los plugins [Sorting plug-ins Datatable](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendrías que agregar el separador de miles y decimales, de la forma en como te indico en el codigo, al instanciar Datatables.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      "language": {
        "decimal": ",",
        "thousands": "."
      }
    });
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" border=1>
<thead>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Cost</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><th>Cust1</th><th>1,00</th><th>200,00</th></tr>
<tr><th>Cust2</th><th>0,00</th><th>0,00</th></tr>
<tr><th>Cust3</th><th>915,00</th><th>1.703,00</th></tr>
<tr><th>Cust4</th><th>1725.237,00</th><th>35.787,00</th></tr>
<tr><th>Cust5</th><th>405,00</th><th>90,00</th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, algo simple y sencillo. Gracias